# Let's Encrypt for hostname and related domain(s) is working, SSL not working for other domains on Directadmin server

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I'd like to use Let's Encrypt certificates for my domains on a directadmin server...

For the hostname is working and I'm able to visit the hostname and the directadmin control panel over SSL, the issue is I can't get certificates to work for my other domains using the directadmin control panel or SSH.

What did I try to solve the issue?

1. [How to enable LetsEncrypt](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=648)
2. [Manually debugging /.well-known/acme-challenge/letsencrypt_12345](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=646)

**Screenshots**
[image]
[image]

If I login to SSH: I'm able to add up to 100 (sub)domains to the hostname, how can I add Let's Encrypt certificate's for my domain's and get them to work? I don't want to use the hostname certificate for the domains..

#### edit 1

directadmin.conf

SSL=1

enable_ssl_sni=1

letsencrypt=1

Output: grep well-known /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf

**Alias /.well-known /var/www/html/.well-known**

[image: Services screenshot directadmin]
Let's Encrypt is running and the certificates renew automatically, the only domains that can use  it are the [hostname](https://ser1.naamhost.nl) and some related domains, The latest version of letsencrypt.sh for directadmin servers is installed. I'm not able to use certificates for my other domains hosted on this server..

Please ask in the comments If you're in need of more information regarding this issue..

Comment: You are looking for a wildcard certificate?

Comment: Please post letsencrypt config and command that is run.

Comment: @030 No, I'd like to get Let's Encrypt to work. Certificates are created by the directadmin cp and the certificates are valid but not working as the domain and it's subdomains are not secured by the certificate(s) at this moment the only way to get SSL secured websites is to add domains to the hostname certificate. I would like to create certificates for a domain and its subdomains, I'd like to be able to create working certificates using the directadmin cp or SSH without using the hostname certificate.. All domains should have their own SSL certificate without using the hostname certificate

Comment: @mzhaase I'll get the information and add it as an edit to my question ASAP

Comment: So you need a SAN certificate or a way for Let's Encrypt to issue a unique certificate for each of the URIs that are served up from that host?

Comment: I need 1 Let's Encrypt certificate for each domain, all domains are served by the same server.. someone told me about CHMOD but he didn't know what rights I should set to `.well-known` current setting is 0755

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: Let's Encrypt has been issuing wildcard certificates since [January 2018](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html).**

> [Does Let’s Encrypt issue wildcard certificates?](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#does-let-s-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates)
>
> Yes. Wildcard issuance must be done via ACMEv2 using the DNS-01
> challenge. See [this post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578) for more technical information.

---

Let's Encrypt <strike>doesn't offer wildcard certificates, but it</strike> offers multi-domain certificates.

> [What services does Let’s Encrypt offer?](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#what-services-does-let-s-encrypt-offer)
>
> Let’s Encrypt offers Domain Validation (DV) certificates. We do not
> offer Organization Validation (OV), Extended Validation (EV), <strike>or
> wildcard certificates,</strike> primarily because we cannot automate issuance
> for those types of certificates.
>
> [Can I get a certificate for multiple domain names (SAN certificates or UCC certificates)?](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#can-i-get-a-certificate-for-multiple-domain-names-san-certificates-or-ucc-certificates)
>
> Yes, the same certificate can contain several different names using
> the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) mechanism.

**With SAN you have one certificate** that covers all your domains. As TLS connection is established before the browser sends the `Host:` header, your HTTPD  doesn't know which certificate to use for the handshake and matches the first one available that matches the IP address. Therefore there was a long *era* you actually needed one IP address for every single certificate. SAN was the only way to have several HTTPS sites on same IP and the certificate needed to be reissued whenever a new alias was added.

That was until [***Server Name Indication* SNI**](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#general), an extension of TLS which allows the client to include the requested hostname in the first message of its SSL handshake. SNI has been there since OpenSSL 0.9.8f from Oct 2007. It has been supported by all major browsers for years. You can easily configure it on [Apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI), it has been supported by [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) since 0.5.23 and was introduced in [IIS 8.0](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability).

As you already have multiple certificates rather than SAN, **you should use SNI**. Allowing SNI is [possible on DirectAdmin](https://directadmin.com/features.php?id=1100). Unfortunately [Serverfault won't give support for web hosting control panels](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels).

Comment: Yes I know it's possible to have a Let's Encrypt certificate for my domains certificates can be requested/created by the control panel or SSH.  certificates are created and renewed but they do not secure my domains, how can I get my individual domains to be protected by a Let's Encrypt certificate valid for the individual domain and it's subdomains only?